# Setting search_path in postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql

I want to set the search_path of my postgresql server from the postgresql.conf but when i put show search_path in the command prompt after restarting the server i can see that the search_path was not modified as you can see below:

```
  search_path
----------------
 "$user",public
```

So what i should do to set search_path correctly.

Comment: Maybe your user has overwritten the global search_path. You can check that with `select usename, useconfig from pg_user`

Comment: usename | useconfig
  ------------+-----------
  Mouadh   |
  postgres  |
  theriaque |
  ORDOBD |

Comment: the useconfig column is empty.

Comment: Please show us the relevant line from your `postgresql.conf` and the output of `select setting, source, boot_val, reset_val from pg_settings where name = 'search_path'`. **Edit** your question, do not post additional information as comments